# How to simultaneously access the same MySQL database in the main column and sidebar of Wordpress?

Tags: plugins, php, mysql

I've wrote some basic custom PHP code for my Wordpress site. The code basically access a MySQL database (a different database from the wordpress database) and displays the information. In addition to running it on the main page, I also need it to run on the sidebar. The code functions perfectly in the main page *or* it functions perfectly in the sidebar, but when I put the code in both, I get the following error in the sidebar:

**Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/kimusubi/public_html/wp-content/plugins/php-code-widget/execphp.php(44) : eval()'d code on line 5**

I thought it was an issue of accessing the same table and database at the same time, but I'm using include_once and closing my connection as soon as I'm done with it, so I'm not sure what the problem is. This is the code that I'm using for the sidebar and the main column page:

```
<?php
include_once 'db_config.php'; //Include database configuration file
$current_user = wp_get_current_user()->user_login; //Get current WP logged in user
try { //Access accounts table and pull user info into associative array
    $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE accnt = :accnt");
    $STH->bindParam(':accnt', $current_user);
    $STH->execute();
    $Result = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $DBH = null;
    }
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo "Select Accounts Table Error: " .$e->getMessage(). "</br>"; //Display Error (if any)
}

$available = min($Result['week_two'],$Result['week_one'],$Result['current']);

echo "Account: " .$Result['accnt']. "</br>";
echo "Name: " .$Result['first']. " " .$Result['last']. "</br>";
echo "Address: " .$Result['address']. ", " .$Result['city']. ", " .$Result['state']. ", " .$Result['zip']. "</br>";
echo "Phone: " .$Result['phone']. "</br>";
echo "Current Balance: $" .$Result['current']. "</br>";
echo "Available Balance: $" .$available. "</br>";
?>
```

And this is what's in my db_config.php file:

```
<?php
try {
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
$DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );

}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo "Select DB Error: " .$e->getMessage(). "</br>";
}

?>
```

Exec-PHP is the only plugin I'm using in order to execute PHP directly from Wordpress. I'd appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all dont use Exec-PHP plugin, instead of it write your own. Second use $wpdb object (instance of WPDB class) to make all calls to database.

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Exec-PHP, so you can take that out of the equation. Run PHP in a page template for the main page [Page Templates « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) with a custom page template.

And use [WordPress › PHP Code Widget « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-code-widget/) to run PHP in a widget; it's bascially a text widget that runs PHP.